# Shading is different for mesh renderer and skinned mesh renderer in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Shading is different for mesh renderer and skinned mesh renderer in Unity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Fac.png)

On the left is the Mesh renderer and on the right is the skinned mesh renderer.
Same mesh, but different shadows.
I don't know how to solve it. I need help.

Comment: Can you try changing your import settings for the models. Under your import settings there should be an option to change your models normals. If it is set to import, change it to calculate and hit apply. You can change the smoothness from Smoothing Angle option under the same import settings

Comment: Thank you for answer. But this setting didn't solve my problem. It was confirmed that it works normally when the Rig option is set to None, but it is a model that requires a Rig.